# select distinct values on a column by passing the column to be filtered dynamically in entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

select distinct Description from Sometable  where condition  = 2000

i have tried acheiving this using reflection but getting an error

```
500 Internal Server Error","error":"{\"message\":\"An error has occurred.\",\"exceptionMessage\":\"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] GetProperties()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Method i have written with linq query

```
   public IList<Material> GetDisctinctColumnValues(string parameter)
           {
                using (var db = this.dbFactory.CreateDbContext())
                {

                    var columns= db.Table.GroupBy(m => ((IQueryable)m).ElementType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == parameter))
                                  .Select(c => c.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
                    return columns;
                }
            }
```

I have to write a linq query based on the parameter which is passed from a method.Lets say the Column is passed as parameter here it is "Description".

Comment: Please add the code, which you have already tried and description of the issue with that code.

Comment: `context.YourTable.Select(x => x.Description).Where(x => x == "2000").Distinct().ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = Table
  .Where(r => r.discreption==2000 })
  .GroupBy(x => x.SomeProperty)
  .Select(x => x.First());
```

**OR**

```
  var res = Table
      .Where(r => r.discreption==2000 })
      .Distinct().ToList();
```

**If you want to `select` only Description:**

```
var res = Table.Select(z=>z.description)
  .Where(r => r.description==2000 })
  .GroupBy(x => x.SomeProperty)
  .Select(x => x.First());
```

**OR**

```
  var res = Table.Select(z=>z.description)
      .Where(r => r.description==2000 })
      .Distinct().ToList();
```